# Is there a pdf library (.Net/C# compatible) that allows for embedding Audio/Video media in a pdf?

Tags: pdf, adobe, components, embed, media

I have a requirement where by I need to attach audio/video media submitted as binary files to be embedded into pdfs that are residing on the server. BTW, the audio/video binary is coming from mobile App.

Is there a pdf library out there that allows for embedding Audio/Video in a pdf? Also, I need these media embedded in the simplest form so that when this pdf containing the media is opened on a target device, there should be no need for installing additional media decoders.

My server side environment is in .Net/C# so would need the pdf library to be compatible with .Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost any PDF for .net supports movie annotations, iTextSharp (open source), TallPDF, xfinium.pdf (i work for this company), pdf4net, docotic.pdf, just to name a few.
The thing is that the media files are embedded as they are (converting video is not their job) and the target machine must have the required codecs in order to play the media. If you have control over the media format, you can choose a format that is supported by many platforms.

Comment: What about a simple audio file - as basic as a .wav file recorded with the sound recorder of Windows? Will the movie annotation support adding this type of a sound file?

Comment: You have to use a sound annotation for audio.